# How to explain Learning With Errors?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lwe

I am trying to understand this concept of Learning With Errors. There does not seem to be a layman explanation of it anywhere. Here I describe layman as someone who understands ML concepts a bit (non expert).

Can someone explain that a bit please? The wiki page refers to Parity Learning which also is not explained anywhere.

I am trying to read up on homomorphic encryption and I am stuck here.

Comment: Boaz Barak's lecture notes are good: http://www.intensecrypto.org/public/lec_12_lattices.html

Comment: The video by Bill Buchanan is a light introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXvoX9uDr8Q

Comment: ML=Machine Learning? Maximum Likelihood?